# How to decode base64 text in ldif file in Linux?

Tags: sed, openldap, base64

I need to decode base64 embedded in ldif (openldap) backups.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139588/2796922) a way to join lines starting with a blank.

Then, based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204536/62756) question about "How to decode base64 text in xml file in Linux?" I want to decode the base64 strings, but I'm not being able to get it to work.

My Script is:

```
#Join lines starting with space
sed -n 'H; ${ x; s/\n//; s/\n //g; p}' "$FILE" > "$FILE_JOINED"

#Decode lines containing base64 (those with double colon)
sed -r 's/(:: )([[:graph:]]+)/\1 '"`grep -oP ':: [[:graph:]]+' "$FILE_JOINED" |cut -c 4- | base64 -d`"'/g' "$FILE_JOINED"
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 297: unknown option to `s'
```

Here I add an example of the "$FILE_JOINED" contents:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=proxy,dc=ldap
olcAccess:: b25lIHZhbHVlCg==
olcAccess: {1}to filter=(&(objectClass=securityPrincipal)(!(pwdAccountLockedTime=*))) attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=Man1,ou=local,dc=proxy,dc=ldap" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {2} to * by * read
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=Man1,ou=local,dc=proxy,dc=ldap
olcRootPW:: dmFsdWUgdHdvCg==
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcSyncrepl:: dmFsdWUgdGhyZWUK
olcMirrorMode: TRUE

dn: olcOverlay={0}unique,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcUniqueConfig
```

(NOTE that the second command leaves the double colon (`::`) instead of leaving only one. I did it on purpose to be able to easily grep the output. I'll fix that later)

The second command has a grep in it: How does it "select" the correct line to decode in all the file contents?

Here is the result of the `grep` command alone:

```
# grep -oP ':: [[:graph:]]+' x |cut -c 4- | base64 -d
one value
value two
value three
```

Could anybody please give me any pointers on how to decode the base64 values contained in a ldif file?

Comment: The problem you're likely having is that the output of `base64 -d` may include a `/` and so is terminating the `sed` statement too early.  You may need to force any `/` to be quoted to protect it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the end I changed the way to do it. Instead of using a `grep` command, I directly echoed the value to be base64 decoded

Comment: see my answer (using perl and  [MIME::Base64](https://perldoc.perl.org/MIME::Base64)) to a **very similar** (almost a dupe) question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735968

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it:

```
sed -r 's/(.*:)(: )([[:graph:]]+)/echo "\1 `echo -n '\\3' |base64 -d`"/ge' "$FILE_JOINED"
```

And if you want to fold the long lines, (based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3798/62756))

```
sed -r 's/(.*:)(: )([[:graph:]]+)/echo "\1 `echo -n '\\3' |base64 -d`"/ge' "$FILE_JOINED" | \
awk -v WIDTH=76 '
{
    space="";
    while (length>WIDTH) {
        print substr($0,1,WIDTH);
        space=" ";
        $0=space substr($0,WIDTH+1);
    }
    print;
}
'
```

---

In case anybody needs it, here is the whole script.

*[Note the script's AWK command leaves alone commented lines (lines beginning with "#") that is not included in the preceding one]*:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1

DIR=`dirname $FILE`
pushd $DIR

WIDTH=76

FILE=`basename $FILE`
FILE_JOINED="`basename $FILE .ldif`-una-linea.ldif"
FILE_DECODED="`basename $FILE .ldif`-decodificado.ldif"

echo
echo DIR: $DIR
echo FILE: $FILE
echo FILE_JOINED: $FILE_JOINED
echo FILE_DECODED: $FILE_DECODED

sed -n 'H; ${ x; s/\n//; s/\n //g; p}' "$FILE" > "$FILE_JOINED"

sed -r 's/(.*:)(: )([[:graph:]]+)/echo "\1 `echo -n '\\3' |base64 -d`"/ge' "$FILE_JOINED" | \
awk -v WIDTH=$WIDTH -v space=" " '
/^[^#]/ {
    while (length>WIDTH) {
        print substr($0,1,WIDTH);
        $0=space substr($0,WIDTH+1);
    }
    print;
}
/^[#]|^$/ {
    print;
}
' > $FILE_DECODED

rm $FILE_JOINED
```

---

UPDATE 20180830

There was an error with shell expansion. It wasn't preserving the "*" characters, but replacing them with a list of files.

The fix was to add double quotes in the first echo command.
I've already fixed the commands and script shown before.

The **ERRONEOUS** command was:

```
sed -r 's/(.*:)(: )([[:graph:]]+)/echo \1 `echo -n '\\3' |base64 -d`/ge' "$FILE_JOINED"
```

---

UPDATE 20180830-b

The AWK command was also modifying comments, and it shouldn't have.

The **PREVIOUS** command was:

```
awk -v WIDTH=$WIDTH '
BEGIN {
    space=" ";
}
{
    while (length>WIDTH) {
        print substr($0,1,WIDTH);
        $0=space substr($0,WIDTH+1);
    }
    print;
}
' > $FILE_DECODED
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your cool base64-stuff, I combine the unwrap and decode to a pipe-cmd:

```
sed -n ':loop N; s/\n //; t loop; P; D' | sed -r 's/(.*:)(: )([[:graph:]]+)/echo "\1 `echo -n '\\3' |base64 -d`"/ge'
```